# Rails: Validating existence of an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Category and a Post model, with each Post belonging to a Category.  Before creating or updating a post, I need to check that the category selected exists.  What's the best way to validate this information?

At the moment, I'm doing a find in the controller to ensure that the category exists.  Is it possible to put these kinds of validations in the model?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/7/14/validate-your-existence

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  validates_presence_of :category 
end
```

-OR-

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  validates :category, presence: true
end
```

Rails versions prior to 3.2:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  validates_existence_of :category 
end
```

Comment: Will this work if the category is scoped?  Say that the category belongs to a Blog.  The user should only be allowed to select categories belonging to to the blog.

Comment: @Homar Not sure about scoping, if the belongs_to association includes this restriction, I'd assume it would work.

Comment: this was renamed to validates_presence_of in newer rails versions

Comment: This doesn't give a very user-friendly error message.  Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @RonLugge - validates_presence_of takes a :message argument, use that to specify your own message.

Answer (score 20):

In Rails 3.2, validates_existence_of is replaced by validates_presence_of.

Comment: also possible is `validates :category, :presence => true`

Answer (score 4):

I've put this in my model:

```
  validate :ensure_category_exists

  def ensure_category_exists
    errors.add('Category') unless self.blog.categories.find_by_id(self.category_id)
  end
```

Which prints "Category is invalid" if the category does not exist for the parent blog.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely worth mentioning my experiences. This is for Rails 4 (potentially other versions as well).

Given an entity has_many or has_one of a model.

Validation that will ensure the entered association (association ID) exists, even if there is an ID given in the submission.

```
validates_presence_of :model
```

IS NOT THE SAME as a validation that will ensure there is something entered (not blank) in the input.

```
validates_presence_of :model_id
```

You may be able to get by with just the former, but I have both to have more specific error messages.

Comment: Issue with `model_od` is that when you just build models with relations, they don't have id before being saved and your validation of parent will blow. I was bitten by this.

Answer (score 0):

In my way of thinking a better choice is this gem: https://github.com/perfectline/validates_existence

It validates the related model's existence in the database. Imagine you have a dropdown field that gives back some garbage data even when you do not select anything (default non selected first field label as value). Validating presence won't work, as it will pass for existing data. But we want some kind of a constraint and this DB side check is what solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In rails 5 and above, `belongs_to` automatically validates for presence.

But if you use `belongs_to :category, optional: true` it does not validate presence, and you can then do `post.update!(category: -1)` which is not great.  To fix that:

```
validates :category, presence: true, if: :category_id
```

Just to be clear, the above is useful only when the association is optional.

Answer (score -2):

In Rails 3, `validates_associated` is probably what you're looking for?
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validates_associated

Comment: `validates_associated` will run the validations on the associated model, and fail the main model if the association is invalid. So it would validate existence, but has additional behavior the OP may or may not want.

Comment: I've tested this and `validates_associated` doesn't break if the associated model doesn't exist (as you would expect). I guess if only fails if the associated model does exist, has validations, and at least one of them fails.

Comment: As obvio171 said, validates_associated does NOT validate the existence of the association.